# php mysql to mysqli optimize

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm converting my mysql to an OO mysqli.

So, I'm not sure about the syntax, if I need to repeat code like below.

I have a php page like this:

```
<?php
...
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $pass, $bd);

//first a select:

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user FROM cad WHERE user = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
$num = $result->num_rows;
 if($num > 0){...}

//an update

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE cadastro SET `user` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

//an insert

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO cad (user) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

//second select

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user FROM cad WHERE user = ? and id=0");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
$num = $result->num_rows;
if ($num==0){...do something...}

...

?>
```

My question is, is it right? The structure is right?
prepare
bind
execute
get result
close...

prepare
bind
execute
close...

...

Or can I be more economic or do it in a optimal way?

Comment: Yes, it is right. I don't think you can optimize anything here.